# Read complex html table with python

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to bring [this table](http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-sistema-pregao-enUS.asp?Data=01/02/2018&Mercadoria=DI1) into a pandas DataFrame. I've tried using pandas `read_html`, I've tried using requests and bs4. I would like to grab the whole table as we see it, but in the html code the table is broken into 3 blocks. Still, I have not figured out how to pin down each one of them.

Here is a starting code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-sistema-pregao-enUS.asp'

response = requests.get(url, params={'Data': '08/01/2018', 'Mercadoria': 'DI1'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: "The names in the divs and classes in the html do not allow me to pin down excatly what I need." Can you "pin it down" clearly enough to explain it to us? We can't help you if we don't understand the problem. Please see [ask].

Comment: @Chris Sorry. I just made some edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing that may help you solve it is the fact that the response you get with `requests` here does not really contain the rendered `table` element, but it definitely contains the desired data.

The problem is, *the page requires javascript to have the table rendered*. You may notice that your data is inside a `script` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var MercFut0 = "";
    var MercFut1 = "";
    var MercFut2 = "";
    var MercFut3 = "";

    MercFut0 = MercFut0 + '<table class="secondary">';
    MercFut0 = MercFut0 + '<tr><td></td></tr>';
    MercFut1 = MercFut1 + '<table class="secondary" id="teste">';
    MercFut1 = MercFut1 + '<tr style="height: 120px;">';
    MercFut2 = MercFut2 + '<table class="secondary" id="teste">';
    MercFut2 = MercFut2 + '<tr style="height: 120px;">';

    MercFut2 = MercFut2 + '<th class="text-center">Open Interest opening*</th>';
    MercFut2 = MercFut2 + '<th class="text-center">Open Interest closing**</th>';
    ...
    MercFut1 = MercFut1 + '</tr>';

    MercFut0 = MercFut0 + '</table>';
    MercFut1 = MercFut1 + '</table>';
    MercFut2 = MercFut2 + '</table>';
    MercFut3 = MercFut3 + '</table>';
    MercadoFut0.innerHTML = MercFut3;
    MercadoFut1.innerHTML = MercFut0;
    MercadoFut2.innerHTML = MercFut1;
    tableShow(2,false);
    tableShow(9,false);
</script>
```

At this point, the easiest approach would probably be to use smth like [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to simply has this page rendered.

Or, you may try getting this script and executing it with, for example, [`pyexecjs`](https://pypi.org/project/PyExecJS/).

Something along these lines:

```
import execjs

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-sistema-pregao-enUS.asp'

response = requests.get(url, params={'Data': '08/01/2018', 'Mercadoria': 'DI1'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# compile the desired table html from the data
script = soup.find("script", text=lambda text: text and 'tableShow' in text and "<table" in text).get_text()
script = """
var MercadoFut0 = {}, 
    MercadoFut1 = {}, 
    MercadoFut2 = {};
var tableShow = function () {};

function getTables() {
    %s
    return [MercFut1, MercFut2, MercFut3];
}
""" % script

ctx = execjs.compile(script)
table1, table2, table3 = ctx.call("getTables")

# parse tables into dataframes
df1 = pd.read_html(table1)[0]
df2 = pd.read_html(table2)[0]
df3 = pd.read_html(table3)[0]

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Then, you can "concat" `df1` and `df2` which should get you the desired table:

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                        0                        1                 2               3                      4                       0                       1              2              3              4              5           6                 7        8         9           10
0   Open Interest opening*  Open Interest closing**  Number of Trades  Trading Volume  Financial Volume (R$)  Previous Settlement***  Indexed Settlement****  Opening Price  Minimum Price  Maximum Price  Average Price  Last Price  Settlement Price   Change  Last Bid  Last Offer
1                   442761                   442761                 0               0                      0                99999.99                       -          0.000          0.000          0.000          0.000       0.000         100000.00    0.01+     0.000       0.000
2                   760332                   792464               147          114160            11351487370                99434.83                99434.83          6.404          6.403          6.410          6.406       6.407          99434.72    0.11-     6.404       6.408
3                  2343218                  2377609               183           99890             9885888562                98967.40                98967.40          6.429          6.421          6.435          6.423       6.425          98967.53    0.13+     0.000       6.425
...
38                   72923                    74133               280            3920              126375887                32296.91                32296.91         11.510         11.450         11.600         11.521      11.580          32063.31  233.60-    11.590      11.610
39                    5325                     5325                 0               0                      0                28878.71                28878.71          0.000          0.000          0.000          0.000       0.000          28649.55  229.16-     0.000      11.680
```